# How to run bitcoind in a low memory environment

Tags: bitcoin-core, memory, cache

I have a Raspberry Pi with 925 MB of memory. Bitcoin Core, operating as a full node, uses between 600-900 MB. How can I reduce `bitcoind`'s memory usage?

I tried setting `maxmempool` to its minimum allowed value, `5`. What about `maxreceivebuffer` and `maxsendbuffer`? Would setting these to a low value reduce memory usage?

Comment: Short comment before writing a full answer: a 5 MB mempool isn't particularly useful. You might as well disable the mempool entirely with `-blocksonly`.

Comment: @PieterWuille That's a good suggestion. I didn't know about that option. It probably lowers memory usage, too. In fact, [this Reddit post on running a node on a 512 MB Raspberry Pi](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/5ffwg2/raspberry_pi_1_b_512mb_ram_running_bitcoind_0131/) mentions using that flag, too.

Comment: With -blocksonly you don't have any mempool at all.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The largest consumers of memory are:

- The memory pool (reduce with `-maxmempool`, or disable entirely with `-blocksonly` if you don't care about unconfirmed transactions).
- The UTXO cache (reduce with `-dbcache`, at the cost of potentially much slower syncing).
- The signature cache (reduce with `-maxsigcachesize`).

In addition, you can also reduce the maximum number of connections (`-maxconnections`) or the number of RPC threads (`-rpcthreads`).

A viable minimum configuration without mempool could be `-blocksonly -dbcache=20 -maxsigcachesize=4 -maxconnections=4 -rpcthreads=1`.

Some advice is also included in the documentation under https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/reduce-memory.md

Comment: `-blocksonly` alone brought my node's memory footprint down to about ~700 MB. I also have `-banscore` set to 1, which seems to help get rid of spammy nodes that flood my node with bad transactions.

Comment: Was still crashing with me! But setting also `maxmempool=100` was causing bitcoind to be at ca. 570MB RSS, that works on my 1GB VPS.

Comment: I used the follow options: blocksonly=1
dbcache=50
maxorphantx=10
maxmempool=100
maxconnections=32 and bitcoind is running smoothly on my raspberrypi with the follow Memory footprint VSZ 422524 and RSZ 266956

Comment: carefully set blocksonly=1，in my case when i set this parameter,the txid cant be added to mempool and stucked for a very long time.no errors in log.

Comment: Some more details available at:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/reduce-memory.md

Answer (score 5):

Followed your parameter:

```
bitcoind -blocksonly=1 -dbcache=50 -maxorphantx=10 -maxmempool=100 &
```

Now I have only 286M memory used with `bitcoind` running.

Comment: Please don't use the "answer" box to write "thank you" type comments.  Please take the [tour] and check [this faq on deleted answers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: In my opinion this answer does add a bit more new information so I don't think it needs to be deleted

Comment: Why are you setting `-maxmemool` if you already have `-blocksonly`? Seems redundant to me but I might be missing something.