# Does running a full node make rpc calls faster?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

Hello I am running a pruning node on my VPS, and some of the RPC calls such as get balance take minutes to load. I need to check the balance every time the users access the website. I was wondering if running a full node would make these RPC calls faster.

The time command shows that bitcoin-cli is taking long due to I/O operations. What could I do?

~$time bitcoin-cli getbalance profit
0.00000000

real    6m16.762s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s

Comment: You're already running a full node. Pruning does not affect RPC speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with pruning.  RPC calls like getbalance only use data stored in the wallet and/or UTXO database.  They don't have any need to refer to the archive of old blocks, and having it available wouldn't help anything.

VPSs often don't have a lot of RAM, and bitcoind in its default configuration needs a lot - say a gigabyte or more.  Is it possible that you're short on physical memory and therefore having to swap?  This can make a system very slow.  You can reduce bitcoind's memory usage somewhat with different options (see [How to run bitcoind in a low memory environment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50580/how-to-run-bitcoind-in-a-low-memory-environment)) but you may also have to configure your VPS with more memory (and pay more).

Another possibility is that your server is overloaded with other tasks.

Either way, running `top` will probably reveal something.