# Bitcoin core download randomly stops

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, installation

my goal is to set up a full bitcoin node. This is my third try, please help.

- Bitcoin core version: 24.0.1
- Hardware spec: MacBook Pro late 2011 i5 4cpu, 4GB ram, 500GB HDD,
- Software: fully formatted with OS linux ubuntu LTS 22.04 minimal installation.
- Internet: 500MB wifi download conecction. 150MB upload.

I also set up in ./bitcoin with nano, a bitcoin.conf with settings :

- server=1
- txindex=1
- daemon=1
- rpcport=8332
- rpcbind=0.0.0.0
- rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
- rpcallowip=10.0.0.0/8
- rpcallowip=172.0.0.0/8
- rpcallowip=192.0.0.0/8
- zmqpubrawblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28332
- zmqpubrawtx=tcp://0.0.0.0:28333
- zmqpubhashblock=tcp://0.0.0.0:28334
- whitelist=127.0.0.1
- rpcauth=bitcoin:[output of rpcauth.py]

So, when I use bitcoind to start bitcoin core, I do not know why it just randomly stops downloading the blockchain at certain blocks and the window terminal closes itself. This issue started around blocks of 2015-09. Also, I should say that sometimes it takes less than a minute and sometimes could be running for 30 mins or more and then shutdown again.

After this, I am opening a new tab, then I use bicoind, bitcoin-cli stop and then again bitcoind to run it back up again. (I do this because I dont know if I need to start and close it right before running it again).

As I can't be every minute running all the time the core download, I would like to ask for help due to, I would like to identify the issue in order to just wait it to download and not be every minute running it:

- It is my hardware?
- It is the peer conection?
- My OS, my btc core version...?
- Etc...

Comment: My guess would be that your Bitcoin Core process is running out of memory and getting killed.

Comment: Thank you Pieter for your answer. getting a better hardware should fix this? If this so, its because ram or drive memory?

Comment: See if any of the advice here helps: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/50580/208

Comment: Thanks for your support!

Comment: Maybe do not use txindex until you know you need it.